# ExpansionPanelList: has no bounded constraint for its cross axis

Tags: flutter

How to make ExpansionPanelList have its own natural width? When it expands or shrinks, the scroll of the SingleChildScrollView should be shown, if necessary.

```
Drawer
  SingleChildScrollView
      Wrap (vertical)
        Center
           Column (mainAxisSize: min)
                 ExpansionPanelList
```

Seen from widget inspector, the drawer has a width of 304, which is set by flutter.

Error:

```
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
RenderListBody must have a bounded constraint for its cross axis.

RenderListBody forces its children to expand to fit the RenderListBody's container, so it must be placed in a parent that constrains the cross axis to a finite dimension.

If you are attempting to nest a RenderListBody with one direction inside one of another direction, you will want to wrap the inner one inside a box that fixes the dimension in that direction, for example, a RenderIntrinsicWidth or RenderIntrinsicHeight object. This is relatively expensive, however.

The relevant error-causing widget was
ExpansionPanelList
```

If the ExpansionPanelList is wrapped with SizedBox(width: 200), it will work. But the width should not be fixed, and it should be match parent. If it is fixed, the ExpansionPanelList may overflow when expanded and cause rendering error.

Comment: the error message has provide a solution: `you will want to wrap the inner one inside a IntrinsictWidth or Intrinsictheight`  widget

Comment: IntrinsictWidth works. Is there a way to set min width to fill the drawer? 
That is, min-width: 100% for web. thanks.

Comment: Can the drawer's width be dynamic and wrap over the ExpansionPanelList? When it expands or shrinks, can the drawer width resize accordingly?

Comment: Another issue: when the ExpansionPanelList width is greater than the drawer width, got overflow error.  The SingleChildScrollView did not show horizontal scroll in this case. It only shows vertical scroll.

Comment: when dealing with size of widget, you have to understand about `constraint`. read this awesome explanation from the documentation : https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/layout/constraints